# Assertion failed even though the expected and actual values are same

Tags: java, selenium, testng, soapui, assertion

```
public class testRunner {
     
     @Test
     public void soapUi() throws XmlException, IOException, SoapUIException 
     {
        
        WsdlProject project=new WsdlProject("C:\\Users\\ALTAF MANSURI\\Documents\\EmployeePortal-soapui-project.xml");  
        
        WsdlTestSuite testsuite=project.getTestSuiteByName("Testing");  
        
        for(int i=0;i<testsuite.getTestCaseCount();i++)
        {   
            
            WsdlTestCase testCase=testsuite.getTestCaseAt(i); 
            
            TestRunner runner=testCase.run(new PropertiesMap(), false);
            
            int statusCode = runner.getStatusCode();
        Assert.assertEquals(com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Submit.Status.FINISHED, runner.getStatus());
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

I get this below error:

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2`
> FAILED: soapUi
> java.lang.AssertionError: expected [FINISHED] but found [FINISHED]

Comment: Expected and actual values shown in AssertionError are result of respective object.toString() values. They are no doubt same, however that doesn't mean the objects are actually equal. Two possibilities I can think of, either they are different objects (in different namespace?) or the equals() method need to be revisited if it's overridden.

Comment: Which type is `runner.getStatus()` returning?

Comment: Hi, I would try to double-toString those values. Like `Assert.assertEquals((com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Submit.Status.FINISHED).toString(), runner.getStatus().toString());`

Comment: @Y-BCause While that would likely get the test to pass, we would no longer be checking whether we are getting the expected type. The test is degraded and less useful.

Comment: @OleV.V., oh, alright :) I wasn't aware that it was necessary.